# to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

I am trying to load the dataframe to sql but I am getting error as below :-

**Error : to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'**

My program as is below : -

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='sock', password='123564', host='127.0.0.1', database='sock')
cursor = cnx.cursor()



source = 'C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\main\\NSE\\Equity_Data - Copy'

files = os.listdir(source)
exten = '.csv'

for f in files:
    if f[-4:] == exten:
        final_path = os.path.join(source, f)
        data = pd.read_csv(final_path, parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print('datafram impport done')

    table = []
    query = []
    with open("C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\main\\NSE\\test.txt", "r") as line:
        for row in line:
            row = row.rstrip('\n')
            table.append(row)
            for tb in table:

                qw = '"{}", con=cnx, if_exists="replace", chunksize=1000'.format(tb)
                query.append(qw)
                print('query append done')

                for que in query:
                   print(que)
                   df.to_sql(que)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case string format should be:

```
qw = '"{0}", con={1}, if_exists="replace", chunksize=1000'.format(tb, cnx)
```

Comment: I have tried to run the program with the updated query you specified but it still says "TypeError: to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'". It seems it is not taking the mysql.connector connection and need sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to program and it started working. below are the edits.

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

1st Update : I used sqlalchemy

`engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://stock:****@localhost/stock')`

2nd update : the string passed to the query previously was not working so I have to use the query like this.

````
                qw = '{0}'.format(tb)
                query.append(qw)

                for que in query:
                    df.to_sql(que, if_exists="append", chunksize=1000, con=engine) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

What you forgot to specify is the connection. You should also pass the connection object as another argument in your code. This is the modified code I suggest might work.

```
df.to_sql(que, cnx)
```

Hope this works for you.